# How to save a connection string from the InstallShield sqllogin dialog

Tags: installshield

How can I get the correct connection string from the **SqlLogin** dialog (DataBase Server) in [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) according to "connection using options" in a simple string for setting the "**content**" of a .xml file element through XML file changes?

See below:

-My XML file format:

```
     <Settings>
           <ConnectionString> "MyConnectionString" </ConnectionString>
    </Settings>
```

If the end user fill in a form like this:

[image]

the content of connectionstring element of .xml file changes to:

```
Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SEPIDAR-ACC-DB;User ID=sa;Password=***
```

And if end-user fill form like this:

[image]

The content of connectionstring element of .xml file changes to:

```
Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SEPIDAR-ACC-DB;integrated Security=true;
```

What I want to set to the Content box of the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: [Using Windows Installer Properties for SQL Login Settings](http://web.archive.org/web/20121211073608/http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/SQL-StoreMSIProps.htm)

You use the properties in your XML changes view to format your connection string.

Comment: ok,thanks,but i want to save it in above formats(for some reasons)

Comment: The formatting is up to you.  Example: Data Source=[IS_SQLSERVER_SERVER];Initial Catalog=[IS_SQLSERVER_DATABASE];User ID=[IS_SQLSERVER_USERNAME];Password=[IS_SQLSERVER_PASSWORD]

Comment: InstallShield doesn't get involved in formatting connection strings because the strings would be different for different data access technologies.  This part is up to you.

Comment: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/SQL-StoreMSIProps.htm